How to make an alias for a common query to run on any database?
I often find myself wanting to run a query like this on multiple different databases:
select n, pg_size_pretty(s) from (
  select n, pg_total_relation_size(n) s from (
    select format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name) n from information_schema.tables
  )
)
order by s desc;

How can I make an alias for this query so that I can psql into any database and run it easily?

I found out I can put an alias in my ~/.psqlrc:
\set tablesizes 'select n, pg_size_pretty(s) from ( select n, pg_total_relation_size(n) s from ( select format(''%I.%I'', table_schema, table_name) n from information_schema.tables)) order by s desc;'

Then I can use it like this:
$ psql $DB_URL
postgres=# :tablesizes
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│                                   n                                   │ pg_size_pretty │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ pg_catalog.pg_proc                                                    │ 1448 kB        │
│ pg_catalog.pg_attribute                                               │ 848 kB         │
│ pg_catalog.pg_rewrite                                                 │ 824 kB         │
│ pg_catalog.pg_description                                             │ 616 kB         │
│ pg_catalog.pg_depend                                                  │ 448 kB         │
│ pg_catalog.pg_statistic                                               │ 336 kB         │


Use CREATE VIEW. It is basically a query alias that is executed every time you access it.

-- create
CREATE TABLE employee (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (0002, 'Dave', 'Accounting');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales');


CREATE VIEW odd_employee AS (
  --- Wrote repeated query here.
  SELECT empId, name
  FROM employee
  WHERE empId % 2 = 1
);

SELECT * FROM odd_employee;

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (0005, 'Alla', 'IT');

SELECT * FROM odd_employee;

Output:
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
CREATE VIEW
 empid | name  
-------+-------
     1 | Clark
     3 | Ava
(2 rows)

INSERT 0 1
 empid | name  
-------+-------
     1 | Clark
     3 | Ava
     5 | Alla
(3 rows)


You still have to create this view on every database you might encounter, if you have the permission to do so. And then you still need to execute a query on this view. Creating a view makes it more complicated and most likely even impossible, without solving the problem

Exactly, even though I could use views, I’d rather not make any modifications to each database I want to run this on.  There are plenty of more specific problems I solve with views already, but I just want a quick way to get sorted table sizes on any db
